# Load balancing setup

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

Server 1(Proxy) -> Server2/Server3(Apache) -> Server4(mySQL)

For server 1 I would setup HARproxy with something like?

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        #log loghost    local0 info
        maxconn 4096
        #debug
        #quiet
        user haproxy
        group haproxy

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        redispatch
        maxconn 2000
        contimeout      5000
        clitimeout      50000
        srvtimeout      50000

listen webfarm 192.168.0.99:80
       mode http
       stats enable
       stats auth someuser:somepassword
       balance roundrobin
       cookie JSESSIONID prefix
       option httpclose
       option forwardfor
       option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
       server webA 192.168.0.102:80 cookie A check
       server webB 192.168.0.103:80 cookie B check
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the long run I think using the `frontend` and `backend` setup will be better as it will give you a little more flexibility.

See https://serverfault.com/a/295093/2561 for a basic example.